# Adding css modal to javascript new open window

Tags: javascript

I want adding class new open window with css model.

```
 class="modal-basic"
```

How can I configure new open window and adding class"modal-basic" to open window with JavaScript ?

```
window.open('jex5.htm','mywindow','width=600,height=500,left=0,top=100');
```

Adding new class window so I don't want to input `width=600,height=500,left=0,top=100`.

```
window.open('jex5.htm','mywindow','clas=modal-basic');
```

Comment: Js fiddle or something? Or explain better please.

Comment: its ajax "sExtends": "ajax",
                  "sButtonText": "Tambah SKOM ",
     "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
                       window.open('jex5.htm','mywindow','width=600,height=500,left=0,top=100');
      }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup window appearance is designed by the browser and css cannot change its styling. If you want to open another location inside a modal just embed an iframe inside a div and style the div to look like your modal.